# Filter the queryset based on the domain making the request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm building a SaaS that will manage several websites on the frontend with NextJS (Universal react framework) using Django Rest Framework.

I want to filter the data based on the domain making the request, on the frontend I'm sending through the headers the domain and on the backend I'm filtering the data based on the domain, the problem is that when I try to return the data with the code below I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Here is my code:

```
class ListProperties(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.Property.objects.all()
    serializer_class = frontend.PropertyCard
    filter_class = filters.PropertyFilterset
    pagination_class = pagination.PropertyPageNumberPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        domain = self.request.META['HTTP_DOMAIN']
        qs = self.filter_queryset(self.queryset.filter(company__domain=domain))
        serialized = self.get_serializer(qs,many=True)
        return Response(serialized.data)
```

The expected result should be the data that corresponds to the domain passed through the headers. Filtered (if filters are applied) and paginated.

Comment: I suggest you take a look into the [django-tenants](https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants) package, perfectly suited for SaaS (and a good implementation of what you're doing manually)! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`qet_queryset`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_querysetself) is supposed to, like the name suggests, return a `QuerySet`, not the response of that queryset. You should simply return:

```
class ListProperties(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.Property.objects.all()
    serializer_class = frontend.PropertyCard
    filter_class = filters.PropertyFilterset
    pagination_class = pagination.PropertyPageNumberPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        domain = self.request.META['HTTP_DOMAIN']
        return self.queryset.filter(company__domain=domain)
```

The `list(..)` function will [automatically apply the defined filters [GitHub]](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.9.x/rest_framework/mixins.py#L39):

> ```
>     def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
>
>         page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
>         if page is not None:
>             serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
>             return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
>
>         serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
>         return Response(serializer.data)
> ```

The (optional) pagination, serialization, and construction of the response are all handled by the [**`ListAPIView`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) itself. If you want to override how the response is constructed for the given queryset, you should override the [**`list(..)`** method [classy]](http://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.generics/ListAPIView.html#list).